# Ordering queryset based on its first child model's attributes, returns duplicated objects. Django, DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-orm

I'm having some trouble with my queryset.
I'm using Django Rest Framework to return:

1. a list of all events,
2. that have a status="Published"
3. ordered by: the most recent upcoming event first.

**Problem**:

Some events have multiple dates. That's why I have separated the dates in a different model.

Now I want to order the event (Parent) based on it's first Date (Child).

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
class EventViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API Endpoint to retrieve Events
    """
    today = timezone.now().date()
    published_events = Event.objects.filter(status__exact="Published")
    ordered_events = published_events.order_by('date__start_date')
    queryset = ordered_events
    serializer_class = EventSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'
```

---

Here are my models:

Event (Parent):

```
class Event(TimeStampedModel):
    DRAFT = "Draft"
    EXPIRED = "Expired"
    PRIVATE = "Private"
    PUBLISHED = "Published"
    EVENT_STATUS_CHOICES = [
        (DRAFT, 'Draft'),
        (EXPIRED, 'Expired'),
        (PRIVATE, 'Private'),
        (PUBLISHED, 'Published')
    ]

    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=EVENT_STATUS_CHOICES, default=DRAFT)

    def event_dates(self):
        """
        Returns all dates of an event
        """
        try:
            date_list = []
            for date in self.dates.order_by('start_date'):
                date_list.append(date.start_date.date())
            return date_list

        except IndexError:
            return "No Dates Specified"

    def event_start_date(self):
        """
        Returns the start date of the event
        """
        try:
            return self.dates.order_by('start_date')[0].start_date.date()
        except IndexError:
            return "No Date Specified"

    def event_start_time(self):
        """
        Returns the start time of the event
        """
        try:
            return self.dates.order_by('start_date')[0].start_date.time()
        except IndexError:
            return "No Time Specified"
```

Date Model (Child):

```
class EventDate(TimeStampedModel):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="dates")
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.start_date)
```

I searched if it was possible to use a model method, but order-by happens on the server side there is no way to call it.

---

How can I return a queryset that orders based on the first child date start_date, without returning an object for every child?

If this sounds confusing please let me know and I will try my best to clarify it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate max child's date first and order query by this value:

```
from django.db.models import Max
ordered_events = published_events.annotate(max_chuld_date=Max("date__start_date")).order_by("max_chuld_date")
```

Comment: This has worked but I'm still struggling to understand what annotate does and what Max does,

Thank you though!

Comment: @TonyKyriakidis welcome! You can find more details about annotation in the doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/

Answer (score 1):

You could add a field called first_date in the the Event model and populate it in a Save signal.

Its duplication but at least it simplifies your query.

```
class Event(TimeStampedModel):
    ...
    first_start_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

In signals:

```
def event_post_save(*, signal, instance, created, raw, **kwargs):
    start_dates = [i.start_date for i in instance.dates.values('start_date')]
    start_dates.sort()
    try:
        instance.first_start_date = start_dates[0]
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Code untested but it gives you the idea.